# Formula for true Glycaemic index (GI) with varibles (mixing foods, cooking and portion size)

Tags: nutrition

Nowadays its considered good advice to inform people whom are tempting to lose weight to avoid high Glycaemic index (GI) foods as these cause the Insulin hormone to be produced at greater amounts and stall weight loss, and promote weight gain, which isn't something people want, or need for a healthier life style, unless your attempting to build muscle mass and strength then sometimes these spikes may be desirable at certain times of the day... pretty common knowledge nowadays.

It really sounds straight forward until you dive deeper and start to consider all the variables, for example:

- Oats rolled have lower GI than Instant Oats
- Oats have a lower GI when mixed with milk than water

Other variables to be taken into consideration is:

- Fibre, fat and other nutritions can lower GI.
- Cooked and processed foods can make the GI higher.
- Mixing foods with others foods can either lower or make the GI higher.
- Even the size of the portion can effect the GI.

So, its clear that GI is very complex and you need to consider all the factors, generally balancing high GI with low GI will offset the total GI, but what isn't clear is how they calculate this all.

Question(s):

Ideally, I'm looking for the formulas to be able to work out the true GI myself, Knowing the stand-alone GI is pretty useless for most people eating proper meals and not snacks.

1. How do you calculate GI when mixing food? for example oats with milk vs water.
2. How is the GI portion size also calculated? this may already be on the site, please link
3. How is the GI calculated for foods that are raw, or cooked?

Comment: I don't have a good reference at hand to write an answer, but the whole reason why it is considered impractical is that such a formula doesn't exist (and probably cannot exist).